# React Hook "useReducer" error when used in contactState function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This error is showing in my contactState function
React Hook "useReducer" is called in function "contactState" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

```
import React, { useReducer } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import uuid from "uuid";
import contactReducer from "./contactReducer";
import contactContext from "./contactContext";

import {
  ADD_CONTACT,
  DELETE_CONTACT,
  UPDATE_CONTACT,
  SET_ALERT,
  REMOVE_ALERT,
  CLEAR_CURRENT,
  FILTER_CONTACTS,
  CLEAR_FILTER,
  SET_CURRENT,
  SET_LOADING,
} from "../types";

const contactState = (props) => {
  const initialState = {
    contacts: [],
    loading: false,
  };

  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(contactReducer, initialState);

  //ADD CONTACT

  //DELETE CONTACT

  //SET CURRENT CONTACT

  //CLEAR CURRENT CONTACT

  //UPDATE CONTACT

  //FILTER CONTACT

  //CLEAR FILTER

  return (
    <contactContext.Provider value={{ contacts: state.contacts }}>
      {props.children}
    </contactContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default contactState;
```

Answer (score 0):

React component names cannot start with a lowercase letter. Rename your component to `ContactState`.

You can see the eslint react hooks plugin check the name [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin-react-hooks/src/RulesOfHooks.js#L42-L54).